# :first and :last in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have something along the lines of :

html :

```
<div class="myclass">
    <img class="otherclass" src="image1.png" />
</div>

<div class="myclass">
    <img class="otherclass" src="image2.png" />
</div>

<div class="myclass">
    <img class="otherclass" src="image3.png" />
</div>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
alert($('.myclass img.otherclass').attr('src'));
```

I am able to get/alert an image src no problem (allthough I cant remember if its the first or last but that is besides the point) - What i want to to is spécicly get the first and last images (src),

I have tried :

```
alert($('.myclass:first img.otherclass').attr('src'));
alert($('.myclass:last img.otherclass').attr('src'));
```

But this does not seem to work for me. (I cannot change the HTML markup)

Am I using :first and :last correctly or should I be using something like .find() ...

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/sSdNR/1

Comment: Your code is working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/y7hHK/

Comment: If it really isn't working, you could try using the `$.first()` and `$.last()` functions instead of a selector.

Comment: What do you mean by _"(I cannot change the HTML markup)"_

Comment: @DidierG. It most likely means he can't edit the HTML markup. It happens sometimes.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RfHps/

However you could try the following:

```
var images = $('.myclass img.otherclass');

alert(images.first().attr('src'));
alert(images.last().attr('src'));
```

Also note that its actually faster to use `.first()`/`.last()` than selectors - see http://jsperf.com/first-performance/2

Comment: The fastest method for first element is: `$(images[0])` and `$(images.get(0))`  http://jsperf.com/get-vs-eq/2

Answer (score 0):

use the `.first()` function.

```
$('.myclass').first().children('.otherclass').attr('src');
$('.myclass').last().children('.otherclass').attr('src');
```